# Magento 1.9 add attribute to Credit memo item

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, model, install-script

I am trying to add a quantity to return to stock data to the credit memo item.

[image: form]

I have made 2 install scripts. One adds a column to the database

```
<?php
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();

$installer->run("
  ALTER TABLE sales_flat_creditmemo_item ADD returned_to_stock INT(10);
");

$installer->endSetup();

?>
```

The second one has to add an attribute to the item so that I can use methods like setReturnToStock(value)

```
<?php
$installer = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/setup', 'sales_setup');

$installer->startSetup();

$installer->addAttribute('creditmemo_item', 'returned_to_stock', array('type' => 'int', 'grid' => true));


$installer->endSetup();

?>
```

The SQL runs just fine, the second script also runs without errors, but when I log a memo item the new field is not there. So I am guessing it doesn't work.

How do I check:

1)The correct syntax for the addAttribute('creditmemo_item'

2)If the attribute has been added or if it didn't work to be 100% sure

Answer (score 0):

Turns out  I didn't need an attribute after all. Just had problems ovverriding the controller thats why the functionality didn't work. Fixed by including the original controller.